# When casting multiple spells do you have to cast the leveled spell first?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I was wondering: when casting multiple spells per turn, does the leveled spell need to be cast first?

The PHB reads:

> **Bonus Action**
>
> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t already taken a bonus action this turn. You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

The way it sounds is that, *if* you cast a spell with a casting time of 1 Bonus Action, you *can't* cast another spell this turn, *unless* it is a cantrip with a casting time of 1 Action.

But why couldn't I simply cast my cantrip first, and then a spell with casting time of 1 Bonus Action?

Comment: It's "turn", not "tern". A [tern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tern) is a kind of bird.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The order of casting does not change the rules. You could cast a bonus action spell (like Misty Step) after casting another spell, or before: but you can't cast *another* spell during the same turn you cast a bonus action spell, unless it is a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

This means that you could cast a 1 action cantrip and then a bonus action Misty step, or a bonus action Misty Step and a 1 action cantrip. But if you've cast a 1 action fireball, you couldn't then cast the bonus action Misty Step. And if you've cast Misty Step, you couldn't then cast Fireball.